# Fill pandas blank groupby rows without resetting the index

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a table like this after group by:

```
t = df.loc[(year-3 <= year) & (year <= year-1), 'Net Sum'].groupby([month, association]).sum()


t
 YearMonth  Type
    1          Other                  27471.73
               base               -14563752.74
               plan                16286620.30
    2          Other                 754691.36
               base                30465722.53
               plan                17906687.29
    3          Other                  20285.92
               base                29339325.21
               plan                15492558.91
```

How can I fill the blanks with grouped Year Month without resetting the index as I'd like to keep YearMonth as index?

Expected Outcome.

```
t
 YearMonth  Type
    1          Other                  27471.73
    1          base               -14563752.74
    1          plan                16286620.30
    2          Other                 754691.36
    2          base                30465722.53
    2          plan                17906687.29
    3          Other                  20285.92
    3          base                29339325.21
    3          plan                15492558.91
```

Comment: It's there, filled and as index already. It's just pandas doesn't print repeated index in MultiIndex setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can only be achieved by altering the display option:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(t)
```

If we refer the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options)

> > display.multi_sparse  True
> >       “Sparsify” MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)

Hence we can set this to False.

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the work

> t.reset_index()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html